# I need to set an HTML web form input value exclusively with javascript

Tags: javascript, webforms

I have a web form that takes the input when a user enters a weight, and I need the kennel size to display according to the weight, right now it only shows "mini" as the page refreshes but never changes.

I think I need another event handler for each time a weight is entered but I'm not quite sure how to do that..

this is what I have written in javascript:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", getKennelSize);
var petForm = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
var petSize;
function getKennelSize() {
    var petWeight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    if (petWeight === NaN) {
        petSize = " ";
    } else if (petWeight <= 4) {
        petSize = "mini";
    } else if (petWeight >= 4 && petWeight <= 12) {
        petSize = "small";
    } else if (petWeight > 12 && petWeight <= 50) {
        petSize = "medium";
    } else {
        petWeight > 50;
        petSize = "large";
    }
    document.getElementById("size").value = petSize;
}
document.getElementById("size").value = petSize;
```

And the elements I'm trying to target in the HTML web form are:

```html
<p>
    <label for="weight">Weight of pet?</label>
    <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" class="quantity" />
    <label for="size">Kennel size</label>
    <input type="text" name="size" id="size" class="cost" readonly>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Comments**

What you are probably looking for is a change or input event on the weight input. Also I would change your weight input to a type of number instead of string.

**HTML**

```html
<p>
    <label for="weight">Weight of pet?</label>
    <input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" step="1" min="0" class="quantity" />
    <label for="size">Kennel size</label>
    <input type="text" name="size" id="size" class="cost" readonly>
</p>
```

**JS**

```js
// Define Variables
const weightElem = document.getElementById("weight");
const sizeElem = document.getElementById("size");
const petForm = document.getElementsByTagName("form");

// Handler
function getKennelSize() {
    const weight = parseFloat( weightElem.value );
    if ( isNaN( weight ) ) sizeElem.value = '';
    else if ( weight <= 4 ) sizeElem.value = 'mini';
    else if ( weight <= 12 ) sizeElem.value = 'small';
    else if ( weight <= 50 ) sizeElem.value = 'medium';
    else sizeElem.value = 'large';
}

// Run handler on window load
window.addEventListener( "load", getKennelSize );

// Run handler on weight change
weightElem.addEventListener( "input", getKennelSize );
```

Answer (score 0):

The load event is fired only once when the whole page has loaded. [["load" event doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)]

```
window.addEventListener("load", getKennelSize)
```

To run getKennelSize function each time the weight changes, replace

```
window.addEventListener("load", getKennelSize)
```

with

```
document.getElementById("weight").addEventListener("change", getKennelSize)
```

also, it seems that `getKennelSize` is a function which calculates and updates `size` value in the html form, so it would be a good practice to name the function `updateKennelSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first up, it not clear why you not using asp.net controls here?

Just drag + drop in the text boxes you need. The reason for this is THEN on page submit or "any" button code for "code behind" code, then that code behind can freely use the controls and values you set in your javascript code.

And while "many" if not boatloads of js code examples wire up a event to the given controls by using page ready etc.? I think to prevent one from winding up in a room with padded walls? I suggest you don't auto-magic wire up events for controls UNLESS you need to, or say often using a jQuery selector to attach a event to many controls.

So, I suggest that you code in such a way that WHEN you look at say a button, or text box, you can "easy see" that control has a event code stub. And that goes for server side events, or client side js events.

And by using "on page ready" or some such? Then WHEN you look at the markup of the controls, you have to now go on some great easter egg hunt to SEE and FIND that these controls have some event attached to them. This makes going back to that page VERY difficult.

From the developer land I come from? if we drop on a page a control or button? Then AT THAT point in time, define the event , or whatever.

And, I do suggest adopting jQuery, as it often does shorten your control referencing.

And like server or client controls? yes, do have/add a "id" for these controls.

So, say this:

```
        <div style="float: left">
            <label for="weight">Weight of pet?</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtWeight" runat="server" 
                ClientIDMode="Static"
                onchange="mycalc()"
                >
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left: 35px">
            <label for="size">Kennel size</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSize" runat="server"  
                ClientIDMode="Static" >
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <script>

            function mycalc() {

                var petWeight = $('#txtWeight').val()
                var petSize = "";

                if (petWeight == "") {
                    petSize = ""
                } else if (petWeight <= 4) {
                    petSize = "mini";
                } else if (petWeight <= 12) {
                    petSize = "small";
                } else if (petWeight <= 50) {
                    petSize = "medium";
                } else {
                    petWeight > 50;
                    petSize = "large";
                }
                $('#txtSize').val(petSize)
            }

        </script>
```

So, now note how we don't "depend" on a wing and a prayer that some "event" is hooked up to the control. We can read/see right away, that the text box has a clinet side on change event.

Now, I did as a "habit" to shorten the control reference, I "often" use/set the clientidmode = static. What that does is prevent the asp.net engine from "messing" around with the "id" that it assigns to the control. This often makes the jQuery (or js document.getelemntbyid) quite a bit easer to write and read.

But, for those that don't care (or want to think about clientidmode), then this is ok also:

```
        <div style="float: left">
            <label for="weight">Weight of pet?</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtWeight" runat="server" 
                ClientIDMode="Static"
                onchange="mycalc()"
                >
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left: 35px">
            <label for="size">Kennel size</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSize" runat="server"  
                ReadOnly="true"
                ClientIDMode="Static" >
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <script>
            function mycalc() {

                var petWeight = $('#<%= txtWeight.ClientID %>').val()
                var petSize = "";

                if (petWeight == "") {
                    petSize = ""
                } else if (petWeight <= 4) {
                    petSize = "mini";
                } else if (petWeight <= 12) {
                    petSize = "small";
                } else if (petWeight <= 50) {
                    petSize = "medium";
                } else {
                    petWeight > 50;
                    petSize = "large";
                }
                $('#<%= txtSize.ClientID %>').val(petSize)
            }

        </script>
```

So, I "suggest" that you don't use "code" to wire up the event, since then that not only makes code hard to read + maintain, but if you ever cut + paste the code, then the "event" define travels with the markup, not buried some place else on the page that does some "page" event, or that attaches some event by having to write code when it is a rather simple matter to define the event for the given control in markup as opposed to writing MORE code to attach the event, and then having to write the event code.

so, for a click event, or onchange (client side code)? I suggest you just define it in the markup, since that's how we all coded for the last 30 years, be it desktop code, or now client side js code?

We drop in a control, and then define the events for that control, kind like we always done.

and as noted, by using those asp.net controls?

Then in code behind, you can say for a button click, do this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print($"Value of Size {txtSize.Text}");
        Debug.Print($"Value of Weight {txtWeight.Text}");

    }
```